# ghc sudden error: -lGLU, -lGL

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, ghc, gloss

I am running `Ubuntu 16.04` in virtualbox on windows 10. I am working with `gloss` in haskell `ghc` and I compiled many files with the `gloss` package without an issue. Then suddenly for no apparent reason, I am getting errors compiling things that used to work. I did not do anything weird as far as I'm aware so I have no idea what is going on. But now I get errors when compiling

```
$ghc Hello
Linking Hello ...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLU
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I try to run a file I compiled previously without recompiling, I get

```
$./Clock
Clock: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)
```

I don't know what could have caused this. What is the proper way to fix this?

EDIT: I installed

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev  mesa-common-dev
```

and it now compiles but I still get the same error when trying to run. I am running linux virtual machine in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

I am still not sure what caused the problem but my guess is that there was some graphics issue especially through virtual machine that suddenly became an issue once I used gloss more intensively.